# PopToRootViewController is not Working after closing app recent tab

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

i'm working on app and its logout function does not working properly.
[**here is image of storyborad**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhXvE.png)

[**here is second image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw2K2.png)

so my problem is when launch the app and logout then is working but when i'm close its recent tab and again try to logout it stop that screen does not going back to login screen.

**here is my logout code**

```
@IBAction func onClickLogOut(_ sender: Any)
{
    do
    {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()

        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isLogin")
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "uid")
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "email")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    }
    catch let err
    {
        print(err.localizedDescription)
    }

    let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let st = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let vc = st.instantiateViewController(identifier: "LoginSignUpVC") as? LoginSignUpVC
    let navVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc!)
    appDel.window?.rootViewController = navVc
    appDel.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    self.parent?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)


}
```

Comment: where is this code located? from where is being call?

Comment: This logout function if call from profilevc which is located in tabbar controller

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean with `close its recent tab`?

Are you sure the event is linked with your logout button on your presenting page?

I don't think `window.makeKeyAndVisible` and `navigationController.popToRootViewController` are needed to be called here.
I would write the redirect logic as follow:

```
@IBAction func onClickLogOut(_ sender: Any)
{
    do
    {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()

        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isLogin")
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "uid")
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "email")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    }
    catch let err
    {
        print(err.localizedDescription)
    }

    guard let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginSignUpVC") as? LoginSignUpVC else {
        print("Error: VC not found")
        return
    }

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let st = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let vc = st.instantiateViewController(identifier: "LoginSignUpVC") as? LoginSignUpVC
    let navVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc!)
    appDel.window?.rootViewController = navVc
    appDel.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

In the above piece of code you are creating new instance of **LoginSignUpVC** and navigation controller and you are setting this instance as root view controller which deallocates previously set root view controller  . Hence popToRootViewController is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are doing `popToRootViewController` after setting the rootviewcontroller to the `LoginSignUpVC`?

It's not required because you already setting rootviewcontroller to `LoginSignUpVC.`

Just remove `popToRootViewController` line from your code.

```
@IBAction func onClickLogOut(_ sender: Any) {

    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()

        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isLogin")
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "uid")
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "email")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
    catch let err {
        print(err.localizedDescription)
    }

    let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let st = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let vc = st.instantiateViewController(identifier: "LoginSignUpVC") as? LoginSignUpVC
    let navVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc!)
    appDel.window?.rootViewController = navVc
}
```

I hope it will work for you!!